# How do I pass an id in a post/put simple_form with - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new to rails so any help offered would be much appreciated.

the aim:

> when a user leaves a note(comment) on a form, i
>   would like to be able to know the userr_id & form_id on that note. I
>   am unsure how to link the form_id to the note. when i create a note, it tells me which user (userr_id) created it but it does not tell me which form (form_id) the note belongs to - any help would be much appreciated - thank you

i currently have the below models and views created

- [model] note belongs_to :userj
- [model] note belongs_to :form
- [model] form has_many :notes
- [model] userj has_many :notes

my console:

```
2.1.2 :062 > ap Note.all
  Note Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "notes".* FROM "notes"
[
    [0] #<Note:0x007fbde666cd70> {
                :id => 4,
           :content => "hello",
           :form_id => nil,
        :created_at => Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:17:19 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:17:19 UTC +00:00,
          :userr_id => 1
    }
]
```

models:

```
note.rb
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userj
  belongs_to :form
end

form.rb
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end

userr.rb
class Userr < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :notes
end
```

forms/show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Firstname:</strong>
  <%= @form.firstname %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Lastname:</strong>
  <%= @form.lastname %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Number:</strong>
  <%= @form.number %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @form.email %>
</p>


<h2> Recruiters Notes on jobseeker form</h2>
<p>
  <%= render 'notes/form' %>
</p>
```

notes/_form.html.erb

> i tried passing the form_id as per below but when i create a note for
>   a form, it does not tell me which form the note belongs to as the
>   form_id column (in the notes table) states nill in the console

```
<%= simple_form_for(@note) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :form_id, value: params[:form_id] %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%# f.button :submit %>
    <%= f.button  :submit , name: "form", value: params[:form_id] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

notes_controller.rb

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @notes = Note.all
    respond_with(@notes)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@note)
  end

  def new
    @note = Note.new
    respond_with(@note)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params)
    @note.userr_id = current_userr.id
    @note.save
    respond_with(@note)
  end

  def update
    @note.update(note_params)
    respond_with(@note)
  end

  def destroy
    @note.destroy
    respond_with(@note)
  end

  private
    def set_note
      @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    end

    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:content, :form_id, :userr_id)
    end
end
```

forms_controller.rb

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    ...
  end

  def show
    @note = Note.new
    respond_with(@form)
  end

  def new
    ...
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
    @form.userj_id = current_userj.id
    if @form.save
      MailerFormsubmission.form_submission_confirmation(@form).deliver
      redirect_to application_submitted_path
    else
      redirect_to userr_advert_path(advert.userr, advert)
    end
    # respond_with(@form)
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    ...
  end

  private
    def set_form
      @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    end

    def form_params
     ....
    end
end
```

Comment: In various places, you have `userj` and `userr`.  Which is it?  Please fix code/post.

Comment: Also, I think you either need to change the first line of your _form partial to `<%= simple_form_for(@form.note) do |f| %>` or associate @note to @form in your controller.  In the partial, you should also not refer explicitly to `form_id` or `params`, just collect the attributes you need for the form instance and create in the controller.

Comment: Is `:form_id` being passed into the params just fine? Can we see your routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you shouldn't try to use params in views. In this case, you could:

1. Build the `@note` instance variable through the association with the form (`@note = @form.notes.build`), in the `FormsController#show`, and include the hidden field in the form;
2. Pass the `@form` instance to the partial, so it can use it in the form:

forms/show.html.erb:

```
    # ...
    <%= render partial: 'notes/form', locals: { form: @form } %>
```

notes/_form.html.erb

```
    # ...
    <%= f.hidden_field :form_id, value: form.id %>
```

Comment: thank you @mrodrigues it worked, what will be the best practise though in achieving this? should i have made notes a nested resource under form?